# D3 bubble chart toggle buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and trying to create a bubble chart with a toggle button to switch different candidates of the presidential campaign. I managed to create the chart for one candidate only, but am having trouble doing the toggle with D3.js. I am trying to do something like [this](http://vallandingham.me/vis/gates/), but less sophisticated and with lesser animation. How do I do this?

My HTML is as follows:

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgithub.com/Caged/d3-tip/master/examples/example-styles.css">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src= "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src= "d3-tip.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <h1> Who's Giving Them Money? </h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p> A look at the individual contributions to prominent candidates in the 2016 presidential campaign. The visualization below looks at the amount per 1,000 persons in each state of the US. Data has been sourced from the <strong> Federal Election Commission </strong> website, and is from April 1, 2015 to September 30, 2015. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default hillary dem">Hillary Clinton</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default rubio rep">Marco Rubio</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sanders dem">Bernie Sanders</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default bush rep">Jeb Bush</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cruz rep">Ted Cruz</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default trump rep">Donald Trump</button>
    </div>

    <div id ="viz">

    </div>
    <script src= "script.js"></script>


</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
    var tooltip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(
function(d) { return d['Name'] + ': $' + d['Amount'];
});


    var diameter = 500
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                  .domain(['R','D'])
                  .range(['#B2182B','#2166AC']);


    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                   .sort(null)
                   .size([diameter, diameter])
                   .padding(3.5);

    var svg = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter)
        .attr("class", "bubble");


    /* modified d3-tip boilerplate */
    /* Invoke the tip in the context of your visualization */
    svg.call(tooltip);

    d3.csv("Candidates.csv", function(error, data) {

        var nest = d3.nest()
                     .key(function(d){return d['Candidate'] })
                     .entries(data);

var button = d3.select("")


data = data.map(function(d) {
    d.value = +d["Amount"];
    return d;
});

var nodes = bubble.nodes({children: data }).filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
});


var bubbles = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .selectAll(".bubble")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter();

bubbles.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d["Past"]);
    })


//format the text for each bubble
bubbles.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y + 5;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    //.text(function(d){ return d["State"] ; })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d["State"];
    });

bubbles.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    })
    .on('mouseover', tooltip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tooltip.hide);
```

});

And here's my CSV file sample. The full file can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_rsg3wNmSGTT3BaU0NTVlh6ZHc/view?usp=sharing):

```
    Candidate,State,Name,Past,Amount
    Marco Rubio,AK,Alaska,R,10.5
    Hillary Clinton,AL,Alabama,R,10.47
    Jeb Bush,AR,Arkansas,R,4.55
    Donald Trump,AZ,Arizona,R,46.13
    Ted Cruz,CA,California,D,82.55
```

Just for clarification, the 'Past' field shows how the states have voted in the past (Republican/Democrat), Sorry if I made any mistakes in the post. This is my first ever post! I'd really appreciate if you could help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// d3.tip
// Copyright (c) 2013 Justin Palmer
//
// Tooltips for d3.js SVG visualizations

(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module with d3 as a dependency.
    define(['d3'], factory)
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = function(d3) {
      d3.tip = factory(d3)
      return d3.tip
    }
  } else {
    // Browser global.
    root.d3.tip = factory(root.d3)
  }
}(this, function (d3) {

  // Public - contructs a new tooltip
  //
  // Returns a tip
  return function() {
    var direction = d3_tip_direction,
        offset    = d3_tip_offset,
        html      = d3_tip_html,
        node      = initNode(),
        svg       = null,
        point     = null,
        target    = null

    function tip(vis) {
      svg = getSVGNode(vis)
      point = svg.createSVGPoint()
      document.body.appendChild(node)
    }

    // Public - show the tooltip on the screen
    //
    // Returns a tip
    tip.show = function() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
      if(args[args.length - 1] instanceof SVGElement) target = args.pop()

      var content = html.apply(this, args),
          poffset = offset.apply(this, args),
          dir     = direction.apply(this, args),
          nodel   = getNodeEl(),
          i       = directions.length,
          coords,
          scrollTop  = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop,
          scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft

      nodel.html(content)
        .style({ opacity: 1, 'pointer-events': 'all' })

      while(i--) nodel.classed(directions[i], false)
      coords = direction_callbacks.get(dir).apply(this)
      nodel.classed(dir, true).style({
        top: (coords.top +  poffset[0]) + scrollTop + 'px',
        left: (coords.left + poffset[1]) + scrollLeft + 'px'
      })

      return tip
    }

    // Public - hide the tooltip
    //
    // Returns a tip
    tip.hide = function() {
      var nodel = getNodeEl()
      nodel.style({ opacity: 0, 'pointer-events': 'none' })
      return tip
    }

    // Public: Proxy attr calls to the d3 tip container.  Sets or gets attribute value.
    //
    // n - name of the attribute
    // v - value of the attribute
    //
    // Returns tip or attribute value
    tip.attr = function(n, v) {
      if (arguments.length < 2 && typeof n === 'string') {
        return getNodeEl().attr(n)
      } else {
        var args =  Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        d3.selection.prototype.attr.apply(getNodeEl(), args)
      }

      return tip
    }

    // Public: Proxy style calls to the d3 tip container.  Sets or gets a style value.
    //
    // n - name of the property
    // v - value of the property
    //
    // Returns tip or style property value
    tip.style = function(n, v) {
      if (arguments.length < 2 && typeof n === 'string') {
        return getNodeEl().style(n)
      } else {
        var args =  Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        d3.selection.prototype.style.apply(getNodeEl(), args)
      }

      return tip
    }

    // Public: Set or get the direction of the tooltip
    //
    // v - One of n(north), s(south), e(east), or w(west), nw(northwest),
    //     sw(southwest), ne(northeast) or se(southeast)
    //
    // Returns tip or direction
    tip.direction = function(v) {
      if (!arguments.length) return direction
      direction = v == null ? v : d3.functor(v)

      return tip
    }

    // Public: Sets or gets the offset of the tip
    //
    // v - Array of [x, y] offset
    //
    // Returns offset or
    tip.offset = function(v) {
      if (!arguments.length) return offset
      offset = v == null ? v : d3.functor(v)

      return tip
    }

    // Public: sets or gets the html value of the tooltip
    //
    // v - String value of the tip
    //
    // Returns html value or tip
    tip.html = function(v) {
      if (!arguments.length) return html
      html = v == null ? v : d3.functor(v)

      return tip
    }

    // Public: destroys the tooltip and removes it from the DOM
    //
    // Returns a tip
    tip.destroy = function() {
      if(node) {
        getNodeEl().remove();
        node = null;
      }
      return tip;
    }

    function d3_tip_direction() { return 'n' }
    function d3_tip_offset() { return [0, 0] }
    function d3_tip_html() { return ' ' }

    var direction_callbacks = d3.map({
      n:  direction_n,
      s:  direction_s,
      e:  direction_e,
      w:  direction_w,
      nw: direction_nw,
      ne: direction_ne,
      sw: direction_sw,
      se: direction_se
    }),

    directions = direction_callbacks.keys()

    function direction_n() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.n.y - node.offsetHeight,
        left: bbox.n.x - node.offsetWidth / 2
      }
    }

    function direction_s() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.s.y,
        left: bbox.s.x - node.offsetWidth / 2
      }
    }

    function direction_e() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.e.y - node.offsetHeight / 2,
        left: bbox.e.x
      }
    }

    function direction_w() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.w.y - node.offsetHeight / 2,
        left: bbox.w.x - node.offsetWidth
      }
    }

    function direction_nw() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.nw.y - node.offsetHeight,
        left: bbox.nw.x - node.offsetWidth
      }
    }

    function direction_ne() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.ne.y - node.offsetHeight,
        left: bbox.ne.x
      }
    }

    function direction_sw() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.sw.y,
        left: bbox.sw.x - node.offsetWidth
      }
    }

    function direction_se() {
      var bbox = getScreenBBox()
      return {
        top:  bbox.se.y,
        left: bbox.e.x
      }
    }

    function initNode() {
      var node = d3.select(document.createElement('div'))
      node.style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        opacity: 0,
        'pointer-events': 'none',
        'box-sizing': 'border-box'
      })

      return node.node()
    }

    function getSVGNode(el) {
      el = el.node()
      if(el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'svg')
        return el

      return el.ownerSVGElement
    }

    function getNodeEl() {
      if(node === null) {
        node = initNode();
        // re-add node to DOM
        document.body.appendChild(node);
      };
      return d3.select(node);
    }

    // Private - gets the screen coordinates of a shape
    //
    // Given a shape on the screen, will return an SVGPoint for the directions
    // n(north), s(south), e(east), w(west), ne(northeast), se(southeast), nw(northwest),
    // sw(southwest).
    //
    //    +-+-+
    //    |   |
    //    +   +
    //    |   |
    //    +-+-+
    //
    // Returns an Object {n, s, e, w, nw, sw, ne, se}
    function getScreenBBox() {
      var targetel   = target || d3.event.target;

      while ('undefined' === typeof targetel.getScreenCTM && 'undefined' === targetel.parentNode) {
          targetel = targetel.parentNode;
      }

      var bbox       = {},
          matrix     = targetel.getScreenCTM(),
          tbbox      = targetel.getBBox(),
          width      = tbbox.width,
          height     = tbbox.height,
          x          = tbbox.x,
          y          = tbbox.y

      point.x = x
      point.y = y
      bbox.nw = point.matrixTransform(matrix)
      point.x += width
      bbox.ne = point.matrixTransform(matrix)
      point.y += height
      bbox.se = point.matrixTransform(matrix)
      point.x -= width
      bbox.sw = point.matrixTransform(matrix)
      point.y -= height / 2
      bbox.w  = point.matrixTransform(matrix)
      point.x += width
      bbox.e = point.matrixTransform(matrix)
      point.x -= width / 2
      point.y -= height / 2
      bbox.n = point.matrixTransform(matrix)
      point.y += height
      bbox.s = point.matrixTransform(matrix)

      return bbox
    }

    return tip
  };

}));


var tooltip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(
function(d) { return d['Name'] + ': $' + d['Amount'];
});


    var diameter = 500
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                  .domain(['R','D'])
                  .range(['#B2182B','#2166AC']);


    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                   .sort(null)
                   .size([diameter, diameter])
                   .padding(3.5);

    var svg = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter)
        .attr("class", "bubble");


    /* modified d3-tip boilerplate */
    /* Invoke the tip in the context of your visualization */
    svg.call(tooltip);
var data=[
{Candidate:"Marco",State:"AK",Name:"Alaska",Past:"R",Amount:10.5},
{Candidate:"Hillary Clinton",State:"AL",Name:"Alabama",Past:"R",Amount:10.47},
{Candidate:"Jeb Bush",State:"AR",Name:"Arkansas",Past:"R",Amount:4.55},
{Candidate:"Donald Trump",State:"AZ",Name:"Arizona",Past:"R",Amount:46.13},
{Candidate:"Ted Cruz",State:"CA",Name:"California",Past:"D",Amount:82.55}
];
draw(data);
    //d3.csv("Candidates.csv", function(error, data) {
function draw(data){
        var nest = d3.nest()
                     .key(function(d){return d['Candidate'] })
                     .entries(data);

//var button = d3.select("")


data = data.map(function(d) {
    d.value = +d["Amount"];
    return d;
});

var nodes = bubble.nodes({children: data }).filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
});

console.log(nodes);
var bubbles = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .selectAll(".bubble")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter();

bubbles.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d["Past"]);
    })


//format the text for each bubble
bubbles.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y + 5;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    //.text(function(d){ return d["State"] ; })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d["State"];
    });

bubbles.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    })
    .on('mouseover', tooltip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tooltip.hide);
    //});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<link href="https://rawgithub.com/Caged/d3-tip/master/examples/example-styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://vallandingham.me/vis/gates/js/CustomTooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h1> Who's Giving Them Money? </h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p> A look at the individual contributions to prominent candidates in the 2016 presidential campaign. The visualization below looks at the amount per 1,000 persons in each state of the US. Data has been sourced from the <strong> Federal Election Commission </strong> website, and is from April 1, 2015 to September 30, 2015. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default hillary dem">Hillary Clinton</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default rubio rep">Marco Rubio</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sanders dem">Bernie Sanders</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default bush rep">Jeb Bush</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cruz rep">Ted Cruz</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default trump rep">Donald Trump</button>
    </div>

    <div id ="viz">

    </div>
    


</div>
```

I've done up to here,
And you are looking for whenever we press on buttons like Hillary Clinton, Marco Rubio, Bernie Sanders etc what do you want to show....
Describe a little so that we can achieve it.
Hope you understood.

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn't clear earlier. So if I press the individual buttons, only the results for that candidate should show up.

Comment: It is already showing per user, understand the visualization properly. But just we are showing the State name by d['State'].

Comment: I meant, if you click on Trump, only the circles for Trump should show and all others should disappear.